# Enthalpy change of dissolving air in water?

Tags: enthalpy

I'm looking for a value of the enthalpy change of dissolving air in water but can't find it. In other words, if I pull a vacuum over some water to remove all the air, per Henry's Law, how much energy change would I expect in the water as the normally-dissolved air evolved?

I tried searching for enthalpy of solvation of air in water and looking up N2(aq), etc., in standard thermodynamic  tables, but didn't get results for either one.

Comment: Given that you can look up the solubility of air in water as a function of temperature, you could calculate the enthalpy change using the van't Hoff equation (which shows the relationship between the enthalpy change and the temperature-dependence of the equilibrium constant):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation